# How is the weight vector calculated when using kernel trick for ridge regression

Tags: regression, ridge-regression, kernel-trick

Im trying to understand how kernelized ridge regression works, and how we manage to first transform, and subsequently learn on higher-dimensional features without explicitly having to calculate them.

So far this makes sense:

$ \hat{\beta} = (X^TX + \lambda I_n)^{-1} X^T Y = X^T (XX^T + \lambda I_n)^{-1} Y$

Where we can replace $ X $ with the feature transformation of our kernel $\phi$ as such:

$ \hat{\beta} = \phi(x)^T (\phi(x)\phi(x)^T + \lambda I_n)^{-1} Y$

And accordingly during inference when we calculate $\hat{\beta}^\top\phi(x)$, we are left with:

$Y(\phi(x)\phi(x)^T + \lambda I_n)^{-1}\phi(x)^T\phi(x) = Y(K^T + \lambda I_n)^{-1}k(x)$

Which doesn't require us to actually calculate $\phi(x)$ because we can simply use our kernel function and matrix.

Great! However my confusion stems from calculating $\hat\beta$ in the first place. In the second equation it is clearly dependent on the leading $\phi(x)^T$ which tells me that in order to calculate $\hat\beta$, we do indeed have to perform the transformation of our orignial $X$, negating the benefits of using the kernel trick?

I would be very grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: that's right, when doing kernel regression in general, we don't try to recover a weight vector. In the case of a nondegenerate kernel, this would be an infinitely long vector! So not possible to compute. We work directly with predictions.